# Parking near London

Tags: london, automobiles

I have a rented car and I want to go to London on Sunday. I **really** don't want to drive on those crowded streets, so I just want to park somewhere outside of London Center and than take public transportation. Also, I hope to avoid paying that congestion tax.

So, what do you recommend? I'm coming from Dartford.

Comment: Are you open to traveling by train? Dartford appears to have a railway station with a large parking lot and frequent direct trains into London.

Comment: You don't pay the Congestion Charge on a Saturday or Sunday, nor on any day when you don't drive a car into central London. There is also the Ultra Low Emmissions Zone charge in the same area on all days of the week, but a newish rental car will probably comply anyway.

Comment: By car is comfortable and we will be more flexible. I will save time and money too, I'm already paying for the car. It will be some kind of road trip.

Comment: This does not compute. According to the question you want to _park the car somewhere outside London and then take public transportation_. According to your comment here you have decided _not_ to go by public transportation and take the car  instead because that "will be more flexible". If so, what is your question? Make up your mind!

Comment: @DragosMorar Which is more comfortable is a matter of personal preference. You will probably save money going by car, depending on what parking costs you in London vs at Dartford station. As far as time and flexibility are concerned, train is under an hour to Charing Cross, which is a major bus hub, and the Sunday service is about once every 10 to 15 minutes.

Comment: There is also a contradiction between "Some kind of road trip" and "I really don't want to drive on those crowded streets."

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think the OP is hoping to find cheap parking somewhere much closer to the center of London than Dartford with good public transit into the center.

Comment: Related (shown on the panel on the right), but not sure if it is a duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24934/where-can-i-stash-a-rental-car-while-visiting-london

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I stash a rental car while visiting London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24934/where-can-i-stash-a-rental-car-while-visiting-london)

Answer (score 16):

Dartford is already practically in London; you are unlikely to get anywhere much nearer. Trains from there go directly to Charing Cross, London Bridge and Victoria, which are right in the centre of town.

Answer (score 5):

https://www.ncp.co.uk/parking-solutions/london-underground-car-parks/ lists all car parks at London Underground stations, from where you can continue into London by Tube.

I don't know how busy these car parks typically are, but [North Greenwich](https://www.ncp.co.uk/find-a-car-park/car-parks/north-greenwich-stn-lul/) looks like the biggest one at a south-east London Tube station, and according to [this page](https://ukparking.dashcardservices.com/dashtube/client/_content.aspx?t=11) it'll cost £7.50 to park there all day on a Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, there is no free parking zone in London and most of the parking spaces are paid. There are many private agencies that provide parking facilities and charge some money.